# PHP - Emscripten Alternative?

Tags: c++, php

The emscripten LLVM-to-JavaScript compiler for Javascript is very interesting and allows for C++ projects to be ported to JS:

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten

Is there is anything like this project for PHP?

One really useful thing it would allow would be to have commandline tools like FFMPEG on shared hosting accounts that don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortinetly there isn't one. I have shared hosting myself and I know how it feels to ask for something and get rejected by the admins for security reasons ... However php has composer which is really powerful! It can install ffmpeg even on shared hosting. Of course you'll be missing most of the codecs. I use it to convert .ass subtitles to .webvtt and it works.

Composer can run mp4box and many more software which you'd want to compile to php.

Comment: Since Emscripten can generate WebAssembly binaries, it's possible to run them in PHP using [wasmer-php](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-php).